# How should I update my wi-fi driver?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, updates

I use Ubuntu16.04 and my laptop model is Asus-n552vw. My wi-fi network doesn't work properly. I thought maybe the problem solved if I update my wi-fi driver. I searched for that but couldn't find how should I do it?

EDIT: My problem is very strange and stupid!
If I connect to my wi-fi network at home that has 512kbps speed, I should disconnect and reconnect for every access to internet! I mean I must disconnect/reconnect to open a new site, then I must do it again for another site, or refreshing the other apps data.

But, If I use a VPN like `windscribe` and connecting to it, my network works well untill I am connected to it!!!

Also when I use other network connections with 2mbps or upper speeds, it seems my network works well again!

Comment: "I update my wi-fi driver" That's not how Linux works. We have 1 generic driver that is updated and when your system updates so does the driver. And we might have 1 closed source driver. This one also gets updated as your system gets updated. You probably have another problem. 16.04 gets the hardware support from 16.10/17.04/17.10 has when 16.04 goes up a point release (16.04.1, 16.04.2 etc). So you will have the latest/newest version of your driver.

Comment: @Rinzwind: I updated my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a Ralink RT3290 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working)

Comment: I'm still having same issue on my 18.04 ubuntu. I'm using a Ralink card on hp 4540. The symptom is exactly as you described it. I found this guide that helped me resolve the issue, please see this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working/253660#253660

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 is very stable so i don't think the driver is you problem. maybe the problem is DNS(you can change it in /etc/resolve.conf) or ISP(if other devices have same problem) or hardware

by the way if you sure the problem is your driver, the drivers is in the Linux (i mean the kernel) you must upgrade your Linux and because you use Ubuntu 16.04 i don't think you can upgrade your Linux in a safely way

you can upgrade your Ubuntu to 17.10 or 18.04(it is not stable yet)

Comment: I updated my question