# Can't Install Ralink RT3290 Driver on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: xubuntu

I am trying to install WIFI driver.

When trying to install [firmware-misc-nonfree](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-misc-nonfree) package I get this error:

```
ham@ubuntu:~$ sudo  apt-get install firmware-misc-nonfree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package firmware-misc-nonfree is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

**UPDATE :**

**(1)**
I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working) solution but it didn't work for me.

**(2)**
When I exucated this command `lspci -k | egrep -i "Wireless|Network|Ralink|RT3290" -A4` 
I didn't get any output

The output of this command `lsusb -t` is:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/7p, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
```

Comment: The link shows a Debian package, not Ubuntu. Some packages are common but not all.

Comment: If installing `firmware-misc-nonfree` works in Debian then, I Ubuntu, you can try to install `linux-firmware` (if not installed yet), reboot and test. That old card should work out of the box though. Also because it's very old and not very good even when it was new, you should consider obtaining a new one. The cheapest you can find is likely to work much better that that one.

Comment: Thank you, I tried installing linux-firmware package if that what you meant then I tried to install the driver again, but didn't have luck I am afraid. maybe it's time to get new card I guess.

Comment: As far I can see the RT3290 is mentioned inside `rt2800pci.ko` kernel module, it needs firmware `/lib/firmware/rt3290.bin` from `linux-firmware`. Please add output of `lspci -k  | egrep -i "Wireless|Network|Ralink|RT3290" -A4` and `lsusb -t` to the question.

Comment: Already tried the steps in that link none of them worked for me