# rt3290 wireless not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, ralink

I have a HP ProBook 4540s laptop that uses a Ralink RT3290 Wireless adapter. It barely works with Ubuntu. If it does connect, the signal strength is very weak with a very slow Link speed of 6MB/sec, even while I am just 3 meters away from my router. It frequently loses connection as well.

Comment: Have you tried opening the additional drivers app to check if there's a proprietary driver that works with Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, but there is nothing.

Comment: Does these help? https://askubuntu.com/q/253632/27968 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115958/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working-on-debian-jessie

Comment: No, none of them are working. They are all outdated. Seems like the problem is in the kernel since version 4 with no fix yet.

Comment: @groenem were you able to overcome this problem?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: On my PC, it doesn't even turn on.

Comment: I found this solution that seems to work in 2022. https://xn--deepinenespaol-1nb.org/wiki/reparar-y-reinstalar-conexiones-wifi-ralink-y-realtek/#rt3290sta

Comment: check this out maybe https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=318580 , it's fairly recent (distro version came with 5.0 kernel, so possibly extensible to other 5.x kernels). Apparently it might be an issue with power management, where in order to conserver battery, the wifi card doesn't get enough power to maintain a stable connection.

Comment: another person said turning off "Wake by WLAN" in BIOS fixed the issue, maybe see if your BIOS has that option and try it

Comment: Hi, thanks for the more recent feedback on this issue.

The first one did not work for me.
The second one I am not sure yet, but it looks like it is keeping the connection now.
The third one was not the resolution for me, as the "Wake by LAN" was already off in BIOS, but I was still losing connection.

So the second one looks like it is working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where the connection would last like 10 min then die. I found that the solution proposed by SinfMaster in this link worked for me https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115958/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working-on-debian-jessie

Comment: I have already tried that one, but it does not work. I still have a weak and very slow connection that drops frequently, actually more than I can use it.

Comment: I am curious as to why the solutions mentioned so far was only working for kernel 3.x.x. and not anymore for kernel 5. Surely whatever has changed to break the software driver not to work anymore, could be found and brought back from the old workable kernel?