# Wifi is not workinn in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have installed ubuntu 20.04. Installation was successful but wifi is not working properly. I have rt3290 wifi card. It gets connected for few min then get disconnected or get limited and showing ? Mark. I tried to solve by searching online but no method worked for me. I read somewhere there is bug in 20.04 wifi drivers which is not fixed yet so I have to uninstall ubuntu 20.04 buy new wifi card other than rt3290.
Is there any suggestion to keep using ubuntu ?

Rt3290
Product Ralink
Driver rt2800

Comment: have you seen this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a Ralink RT3290 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working)

Comment: These are not working. Most of shared links are broken

Comment: Also, the drivers in the suggested duplicate are for kernel 4.x. Ubuntu 20.04 has Linux kernel 5.4 by default.